# doing GROUP BY when the underlying query already has only single group

Tags: hive

I came across silly scenario somewhere, someone had created a HIVE query like:-

```
SELECT count(*),year,month from table where year=2016 and month=7 group by year,month;
```

It sounds silly to me. Clearly, because we are already filtering rows so that only a single combination of the columns specified in the group by clause will be present. This query is equivalent to the simple query mentioned below:-

```
 SELECT count(*),year,month from table where year=2016 and month=7
```

It's obvious that the GROUP BY was not needed in this situation. Now my question is that will HIVE really try to do GROUP BY in the first query or it will understand that it's trivial to attempt to do a group by? And if it does attempt, will the group by query be little slower compared to the second version?

Answer (score 0):

the group by is needed to produce a group to do the count on.
without the group by it would error due to the count and if you removed the count it would return lots of records for july 2016 rather than just the one

Comment: Why would it return an error? count(*) is an aggregate function that will simply count number of rows in the result set. The issue may arise because of referencing year and month along with count(*) , not because of count(*) itself. So in that case we could modify the query as:-    select count(*),2016 as year, 7 as month from table where year=2016 and month=7.    But we didn't have to get rid of count(*).

Comment: @Dhiraj, but you DID got rid of non-grouped fields.

Comment: the point is that I am able to achieve exactly the same output as the group by query without using group by. My objection was specifically to the point raised by Topher that the query will fail because for count(*) to work a group is needed and there is no group in the second query. There was a group in the second query indeed -- the collection of all the records with year=2016 and month=7 ; so count(*) would have acted on that group. It would have failed due to different reason , not because there is no group

Comment: yea, you are right. My SQL is failing me. I could have sworn I had to do add redundant group by fields because of functions erroring.

Comment: the only other reasons I can think of is to improve the readability of the query or it is code left in from when it was supplying more than one month's worth of data